# Website not opening if i am not using www in the beginning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to upload my Angularjs Website on Google Cloud, now I have an `index.html` where I am setting my `base href` to "https://www.example.com/" now there I am facing a problem that when I am opening my website using `www` then it is getting opened but if I am opening my domain without `www` then it is not getting opened, now after seeing this problem I thought of using `base href` as "https://example.com/" now only my domain is opening when I am using `www` but not working when I am using `www`.

Can anyone please tell me how can I setup my `base url` such that my website will work for both "https://www.example.com" and as well as "https://example.com". Also if this problem isn't related to `base href` then please tell why I am facing this problem.

Also I have all of my `A` record in my Godaddy linked to `@`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, create the base href element through code, pointing to the location where it got loaded from, or create it as a relative base href

Comment: @Icepickle thanks for telling me that, can you please tell me any approach to doing that ??

Comment: well, relative would be something like `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Then what is the use of using domain name in `base href` if everyone is going to use just `"/"`

Comment: It is something related with your host configuration. If you get added your both the links as a **binding** in your hosting setting it will work (This suggestion is based on IIS hosting. You may check with your host provider).

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS but where can i add both of them ??

Comment: @Icepickle I saw in this answer https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92146/can-i-omit-the-domain-name-for-href-in-the-html-base-tag that we should use `base url` as `absolute url` not relative one.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur, I'm not familiar with Google Cloud (were you have hosted your application). you can ask your provider help desk for this configuration if you don't have control on that.

Comment: I hope you then also read the comments, on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) they mention that it's either absolute or relative, I would say try it out and see if it works. Note that setting it to `/` will only work if your website is in the root path of the website

Comment: @Icepickle It is working fine using only `/` just want to ask what did you mean by saying **will only work if your website is on the root path of the website** ?? I don't know whether it is on the root path or not ?? Sorry if it's a trivial question to ask.

Comment: well, setting it to `/` would make the base href for a site under `http://www.example.com/site1` to `http://www.example.com/` ommiting the `site1`

Comment: @Icepickle  No that is not happening because in index.html I am opening the html corresponding to that route `site1` so every case is happening perfectly fine.

Comment: `site1` would just be a subdirectory on the websites root path, maybe we are mixing up our responses a bit ;)

Comment: Yea maybe but thanks for helping me out of here :)